# Display/Hide content above buttons on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following simple `slideToggle` in `jQuery` which you can also find in the `JSFiddle`[here](http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/4/):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel_button").on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle(0);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.panel {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
  <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
  <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
  <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="content_03a">Here goes content2a</div>
  <div class="content_03b">Here goes content2b</div>
</div>


<div class="buttons">
  <div class="panel_button"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button"> Button_03 </div>
</div>
```

---

As you can see in the code my target is to have three `.buttons` and once a `.button` is clicked the corresponding `.contents` are displayed. 
For example when you click on `.button_01` the `.panel` with `.content_01a` and `.content_01b` should be opened.

Therefore, I tried to go with the jQuery `slideToggle` function but it seems only to work if the `.panel` is directly below each `button`. However, in my construction above I need to have the `buttons` **below** all `panels`.

How do I have to change my code to make it work?

Comment: If there is no logic in document flow, you will need to work with `ID`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have data-target to align the click with the panel, and rest you can add your own logic,

Here is the changes I made added `data-target` attribute and `ids` to each panel

You can read [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo) that how bootstrap is using that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
 
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
    if(!$(targetPanel).is(":visible")){
      $(".panel").slideUp();          
    }
    $(targetPanel).slideToggle(0);
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
   border:1px solid white;
}

.panel {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel1" class="panel">
  <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
  <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  Panel1
</div>

<div id="panel2" class="panel">
  <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
  <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
  <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  Panel2
</div>

<div id="panel3" class="panel">
  <div class="content_03a">Here goes content2a</div>
  <div class="content_03b">Here goes content2b</div>
  Panel3
</div>


<div class="buttons">
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but when I click for example on Button_01 the content opens and when I click again on it the content is hidden but opens immediately again and does not stay closed.

Comment: Cool. Thanks it is working now. By the way in my JSfiddle I was using classes instead of IDs and it is working exactly the same way as with IDs so I am wondering why I should go with IDs if it also works with classes?

Comment: @Michi You can go with classes too, its upto you data-target is your choice.

Comment: Another issue I just saw is when I click on Button_03 instead of panel3 the panel2 is opened.

Comment: Where in your jsfiddle? I expect you to understand my code based on that you can change it to your classes

Comment: Both in the code snipped in your answer and in the JSfiddle.

Comment: Can not reproduce please check carefully

Comment: May be because your button2 width is full

Comment: Sorry, everything is working. It seemed only wrong because the content of panel3 is described as 02a and 02b and not as 03a and 03b. Updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/15/. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is the use of adding an active class if it is not used in jquery or css?

Comment: @ameya active classes always used to indicate the current active panel, user should be aware of the the fact that this things is open currently.

Comment: @Justcode That I know but if you inspect your snippet, the active class of previous button is not removed if I click on other button.

Comment: I can see the difference between using classes here http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/15/ and IDs here http://jsfiddle.net/koanfw15/17/. In the second one the panel1 is closed once the panel2 is opened whereas in the first one both panels remain open.

Comment: @ameya that is ok op can easily add `$('.active').removeClass('active');`

Comment: @Michi it is because you didn't handled it well, I expect you to understand my answer, then you can easily update according to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could add an ID to the panels
2. You could wrap the the panels two separate containers. And using the index of the button clicked to toggle the respective panel inside the panel wrapper. **This way you won't need to specify the panel ID every time and is more flexible**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel_button").on('click', function () {
        const buttonIndex = $(this).index();
        $(".panels").children().eq(buttonIndex).slideToggle(0);
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.panel {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
    <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
    <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
    <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
    <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="panel_button"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button"> Button_03 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you. I have made the code so that only one panel is visible at a time using a simple IF - Else condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel_button").on('click', function() {
    $(".panel").slideUp();
    var targetPanel = $(this).attr('data-target');
    if($(targetPanel).hasClass('active')){
      $(targetPanel).removeClass('active').slideUp();
    }else{
      $(".panel").removeClass('active');
      $(targetPanel).addClass('active').slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.panel_button {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.panel {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="panel1">
  <div class="content_01a">Here goes content1a</div>
  <div class="content_01b">Here goes content1b</div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="panel2">
  <div class="content_02a">Here goes content2a</div>
  <div class="content_02b">Here goes content2b</div>
  <div class="content_02c">Here goes content2c</div>
</div>

<div class="panel" id="panel3">
  <div class="content_03a">Here goes content3a</div>
  <div class="content_03b">Here goes content3b</div>
</div>


<div class="buttons">
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel1"> Button_01 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel2"> Button_02 </div>
  <div class="panel_button" data-target="#panel3"> Button_03 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're Welcome! :)